# Could not load file or assembly 'txkernel, Version=20.0.2000.500

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2012

When I am trying to open existing project in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate, I am getting below error message.

Error:

---

### Microsoft Visual Studio

The control System.Windows.Forms.Panel has thrown an unhandled exception in the designer and has been disabled.

Exception:

Could not load file or assembly 'txkernel, Version=20.0.2000.500, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6b83fe9a75cfb638' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

### Stack trace:

OK

==================================

I am using 64 bit machine to compile my program. 
I checked the below link --> http://www.textcontrol.com/en_US/sup...bute_files.htm

And I did what's mentioned in this page but still I am unable to open Windows Form and getting error message. Please help

Comment: link is broken; and where does this `txkernel.dll` reside? can you see it in the Reference list?

Comment: Contact the vendor of the control for support.

Comment: Broken Link http://www.textcontrol.com/en_US/support/documentation/dotnet/n_distribute_files.htm